# What are the advantages of creating a class to keep track of a variable we decrement, instead of decrementing it in the recursive calls?

Tags: python, recursion

I am writing a solution to the problem where need to to `return the k-th largest node in a BST (binary search tree)`.

In a nutshell, the solution is to do a `reverse in-order traversal` (which when performed on a BST produces sorted valued in reverse order). Then simply stop once we have visited k nodes.

Here is a solution:

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


class TreeInfo: 
    def __init__(self, numberOfNodesVisited,latestVisitedNodeValue): 
        self.numberOfNodesVisited = numberOfNodesVisited
        self.latestVisitedNodeValue = latestVisitedNodeValue
        
def findKthLargestValueInBst(tree, k):
    treeInfo = TreeInfo(0,-1)  #
    reverseInOrderTraversal(tree,k,treeInfo)
    return treeInfo.latestVisitedNodeValue


def reverseInOrderTraversal(node,k,treeInfo): 
    if not node or treeInfo.numberOfNodesVisited >= k:   
        return                                           
    
    
    reverseInOrderTraversal(node.right,k,treeInfo)
    if treeInfo.numberOfNodesVisited < k: 
        treeInfo.numberOfNodesVisited += 1
        treeInfo.latestVisitedNodeValue = node.value 
        
        reverseInOrderTraversal(node.left,k,treeInfo)
```

In this solution, the `TreeInfo class` is used to keep track of the `numberOfNodesVisited` as we call the recursive cases, and also it is used to keep track of the `latestedVisitedNode` value, which we will return at the end.

My questions are:

1. Do we need to create this class, or is it possible to keep track of the number of nodes we visited in the recursive calls?? And decrement k for each recursive call until it hits 0, then return whatever value of the current node is?
2. Am I right in saying that the `TreeInfo class` is a `global class/variable`, and the reason we created it is because we can track k easier as a global variable, instead of locally?

Comment: At no point in the supplied code sample is the class used `BTS()`

Comment: Doesn't quite answer my question but sure. BST class is used on the 'IDE' where I am solving this problem, it is used to run the preset test cases; for reference this is on Algoexpert